# Is using PostgreSQL on stateless FaaS like AWS lambda a good idea?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda

I'd like to use Postgresql as a database on my AWS lambda functions but I'm worried about performance.

I'm worried that Lambdas are stateless and only exist in the time they're executing so I imagine every time the Lambda is triggered it'll try to initiate a brand new PG connection.

I'm not sure if this decreases performance or causes issues with stale connections somehow. Anyone know more about this?

I know DynamoDB is more in line with Lambda but I really need a relational database but at the same time Lambda's scalability.

Comment: How long is each task going to be running for on Lambda? I' thinking this only matters if the db connection time is a significant proportion of overall time, and even then if you need RDBMS functionality then maybe it's a price worth paying. But first I'd try to quantify the impact.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Usually a lambda function would take 100-200ms MAX, maybe about 2 selects and 1 insert every request. but I'm expecting high concurrency. Would you recommend using this project called PostgREST to bypass the legacy connection handshake?

Comment: Handling possible connections limitation, you may also want to look [PgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) for connections pooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [container execution model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html) of AWS lambda. When a lambda is invoked, AWS spins up a container to run the code inside the handler function. So if you define the PG connection outside the handler function it will be shared among the invocations of Lambda functions. You can find that in the above link.

> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in subsequent invocations. You can add logic in your code to check if a connection already exists before creating one.

```
const pg = require('pg');
const client = new pg.Client(<connection_string>);

exports.handler = (event, context, cb) => {  
  client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ', (err, users) => {
    // Do stuff with users
    cb(null); // Finish the function cleanly
});
};
```

Refer [this](http://blog.rowanudell.com/database-connections-in-lambda/) blog post.

But there is a caveat.

> When you write your Lambda function code, do not assume that AWS Lambda always reuses the container because AWS Lambda may choose not to reuse the container. Depending on various other factors, AWS Lambda may simply create a new container instead of reusing an existing container.

Additionally you can create a scheduled job to warm up lambda function. (runs in every 5mins)

Comment: Great answer - very helpful indeed!